# Publishing my React website to GitHub pages just produces a blank page

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I'm probably missing something really obvious but I'm not very accustomed to GitHub or React so I'd love some advice.

My GitHub is here:
https://github.com/SarahACollins/PortfolioWebsite

I've tried publishing the website here:
https://sarahacollins.github.io/PortfolioWebsite/
and it just produces a blank page. I've tried several different ways of fixing (changing the homepage, moving the index.html to the front, etc.) but can't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this resolved or not ?

Comment: No, the page is still blank.

Comment: Which article did you followed while trying this, share the link of that? It seems like you haven't created the build of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the developer console it says:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Looking at the location of the error shows that it is node.js code.:

```
import React from 'react';
```

You need to compile your react source code and create a .js file for the client from it.

Comment: Possibly fixed that issue but then another popped up telling me that I had an unexpected token of '<' within my index.js, here: https://github.com/SarahACollins/PortfolioWebsite/blob/main/src/index.js